# Animating View out from right and in from left

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view within my view controller that I would like to make it animate leaving the view out from the right side of the screen and then have it animate into the center of the screen from the left side of the screen (To appear that a new view is being brought in with new information on it). I know how to make the view animate out to the right or to the left but I am unsure how to make it go out from the right side and in from the left. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could we see some code you're trying to get working?

Answer (score 0):

On a high level, I would say animate it off screen to the right (you said you know how to do that), then make it hidden and reset its frame to be on the left of your screen, then make it visible and animate it back into view from the left (you also said you know how to do that).  You might not even need to hide it...but it feels "safer" to me.

Answer (score 0):

In from right

```
yourView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:self.view.frame.size.width, y: yourView.frame.origin.y)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    yourView.center = CGPoint(x:self.view.center.x, y:self.view.center.y)
}, completion: { (value: Bool) in })
```

out to left

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    yourView.center = CGPoint(x:-yourView.frame.size.width, y:self.view.center.y)
}, completion: { (value: Bool) in })
```